# Using pyFasst occur happens，help me ?3q

Tags: speech

when I install pyFasst:

1) execue " python setup.py build_ext --inplace" ,it's successful

2) install pyFasst,  occur happens：
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
Traceback (most recent call l

```
self.build_extension(ext)
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 173, in build_extension
AttributeError: Extension instance has no attribute '_convert_pyx_sources_to_lang'
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an undeclared dependency on Cython as mentioned here: https://github.com/wslihgt/pyfasst/issues/3

Running `pip install cython` first, then `pip install pyfasst` worked for me.

Comment: notably, this is for python2 only (also, pre-req numpy may have to be manually pip installed first; other dependencies should be handled by pip).  On python3, there are different errors and it does not seem to install, and doesn't seem to be supported as per https://github.com/wslihgt/pyfasst/issues/6